# Getting a form to reset

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I designed a contact form and it works great except for one thing. Whenever someone doesn't fill in a field or if an invalid email address is entered wrong, it stops the form from sending, but then if you try to enter the information in again and hit send, it does nothing. How can I get the form to be able to send again without wiping out the information entered?

The form can be viewed at:

http://sundayfundayleague.com/contact

Does anyone have any idea how I can do this?

The form:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="mycontactform" >
    <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
    <input type="email" class="inputbaremail" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="message" class="inputbarmessage" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
    <label for="contactButton">
        <input type="button" class="contactButton" value="Send Message" id="submit">
    </label>
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                $('#submit').click(function(){

                    $.post("contactSend.php", $("#mycontactform").serialize(),  function(response) {
                        if (response == 'Your email was sent!') {
                            $('#contactMessageStatus').append(response);
                            $('#contactMessageStatus').addClass("contactSuccess");
                            $('html, body').animate({
                                scrollTop: $("#contactMessageStatus").offset().top
                             }, 2000);
                            $('#contactMessageStatus').html(response);
                            $('#contactMessageStatus').delay(5500).fadeOut(400);
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#contactMessageStatus').append(response);
                            $('#contactMessageStatus').addClass("contactFail");
                            $('html, body').animate({
                                scrollTop: $("#contactMessageStatus").offset().top
                             }, 2000);
                            $('#contactMessageStatus').html(response);
                            $('#contactMessageStatus').delay(5500).fadeOut(400);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
```

PHP script that sends the form:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = 'contact@sundayfundayleague.com';
$subject = 'SFL Contact Form Submitted';
$message = 'FROM: '.$name. "<br>" . ' Email: '.$email. "<br>" . 'Message: '.$message;
$headers = 'From: contact@sundayfundayleague.com' . "\r\n";

if (!empty($email)) { 
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 

        //Should also do a check on the mail function
        if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
            echo "Your email was sent!"; // success message
        } else {
            echo "Mail could not be sent!"; // failed message
        }

    } else { 
        //Invalid email
        echo "Invalid Email, please provide a valid email address.";
    }

} else {
    echo "Email Address was not filled out.";
}
```

UPDATE:
Do you mean like this, plus the message area?

```
 if (!empty($email)) { 
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 

    //Should also do a check on the mail function
    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        echo "Your email was sent!"; // success message
    } else {
        echo "Mail could not be sent!"; // failed message
    }
    if($name!== ''){ /*success*/ 
    } else { echo "Please enter a name";
    }

} else { 
    //Invalid email
    echo "Invalid Email, please provide a valid email address.";
}
```

Comment: What happens if you at first instance fill in all information correctly?

Comment: It actually does send the response, just it doesn't update the page to say it was successful. If you look at the network inspection tools of your browser, you can see it makes a request upon clicking send message, and the body of the response is "Your email was sent!"

Comment: A message appears to say it sent successfully, but the contact form doesn't go back to being blank, which I guess that is an issue itself as well.

Comment: Why not use jquery to validate the email on the client side and only submit when it's valid?

Comment: This is what I use to reset a form `$('form[name="form_name"]').trigger('reset');` works if user reloads a page. Could probably be used with a click function.

Comment: @Cruiser Do you think that would be the best approach? Can I check to see if the email is valid and what not? I know I can use the html5 required element, but the more pages I see, it looks as if that is fading away and people are doing more complex validations.

Comment: @Fred-ii- What exactly does that reset? Is it the entire form and do you just create an if statement that if the message was successful it resets? So would I apply that at the bottom of my php script?

Comment: @Becky, you can check to see if it is constructed in a valid way, but not that someone entered a working email. There are regex that will do nicely, without relying on html5 validation, though that's a start

Comment: @Becky I use that inside one of my scripts placed before anything. It will clear all contents if someone submits data and reloads the page. As to how it could be used in your present function could work. I'm a jQuery newbie (sort of), so I'm not the best at implementing this into your present code. *I had to be honest here* ;-)

Comment: *"How can I get the form to be able to send again without wiping out the information entered?"* - Oops, don't use what I suggested, you can use sessions for that, if you're looking to use a PHP method. @Becky but your title *"Getting a form to reset"* is contradictive with your question.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, that would be ideal. Don't worry about my edit then to my questions because it was in regards to your last suggestion. Also to be honest, I am a jquery/ javascript newb as well. I would definitely love to hear about the session method though.

Comment: I think a ternary operator would work best for you. I.e.: For inputs: `value="<?php echo !empty(htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['var'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['var']) : ''; ?>"` - @Becky and starting the session first in PHP `<?php session_start(); // rest of code `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the status visible again, as it has been faded out by the previous error.

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#submit').click(function(){
        $.post("contactSend.php", $("#mycontactform").serialize(),  function(response) {
            if (response == 'Your email was sent!') {
                $('#contactMessageStatus').addClass("contactSuccess");
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#contactMessageStatus").offset().top
                 }, 2000);
                $('#contactMessageStatus').html(response);
                $('#contactMessageStatus').show();
                $('#contactMessageStatus').delay(5500).fadeOut(400, function(){ $(this).removeClass("contactSuccess"); });
                $('#mycontactform').trigger('reset');
            }
            else {
                $('#contactMessageStatus').addClass("contactFail");
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#contactMessageStatus").offset().top
                 }, 2000);
                $('#contactMessageStatus').html(response);
                $('#contactMessageStatus').show();
                $('#contactMessageStatus').delay(5500).fadeOut(400, function(){ $(this).removeClass("contactFail"); });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

As for the extra error messages:

```
 if (!empty($email) && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 
     if($name!== ''){
          //Should also do a check on the mail function
          if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
              echo "Your email was sent!"; // success message
          } else {
              echo "Mail could not be sent!"; // failed message
          }
     } else { 
          echo "Please enter a name";
     }
} else { 
    //Invalid email
    echo "Invalid Email, please provide a valid email address.";
}
```

Comment: So, like this `if (response == 'Your email was sent!') {$('#contactMessageStatus').show();
                            $('#contactMessageStatus').append(response);
                            $('#contactMessageStatus').addClass("contactSuccess");
                            $('html, body').animate({
                                scrollTop: $("#contactMessageStatus").offset().top
                             }, 2000);
                            $('#contactMessageStatus').html(response);
                            $('#contactMessageStatus').delay(50).fadeOut(40);
                        }`

Comment: @Becky That should do it, might want to do it in either case, however

Comment: I tried adding it and it didn't do anything different.

Comment: @Becky It looks like it worked for me, but you also need to remove the contactFail class with removeClass. Have you tried doing a hard reload of the page? ctrl+shift+F5

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure what your code is supposed to change? I did a hard reload and I am not seeing anything different.

Comment: When the user inputs bad details, it causes the message to be displayed, and then fade out. At this point, it's invisible. Once the user puts in new details, the new message comes in, but it's still invisible from the previous fade out. The .show() removes the invisibility.

Comment: That is what I thought you were saying, but I only get the one fail error message shown once after attempting to send the message again. I cleared my cache any everything.

Comment: I've updated the answer, can you try that code? It covers both the success and fail cases

Comment: This makes my error/success box completely go away.

Comment: How about now? I messed up the syntax chaining of removing the class removal.

Comment: Gotcha! That worked and it keeps the content if wrong, but how do I reset the form if the email successfully goes through?

Comment: Hadn't actually looked at the reset bit, should now reset on success using `$('#mycontactform').trigger('reset');`

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks. Even when the email address is correct and let's say the name is not filled in, the error still says "email address not filled in". I know that is because of this `} else {
    echo "Email Address was not filled out.";
}`, but how else can I make it so that the error says what is actually wrong?

Comment: Should just be a case of wrapping `//Should also do a check on the mail function
        if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
            echo "Your email was sent!"; // success message
        } else {
            echo "Mail could not be sent!"; // failed message
        }
` in another check eg. `if($name!== ''){ /*success*/ }else{ echo "bad name"; }`

Comment: That does the same thing then, it just substituted the email not filled in with the name. Is there anyway to do it for all three fields?

Comment: No problem though. It works much better now. I appreciate all of the extended help you have provided!